# php - How to add a custom modal to the admin edit posts page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to add a modal that shows when the set featured image button is clicked. I currently have a simple jquery alert that explains the min widths and heights of the image needed.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#set-post-thumbnail').click( function(){ 
    alert('Thumbnail/Featured images need to be at least width: 450px by height: 640px; '); 
   });
 });
```

I would like to be able to have a more comprehensive visual explanation as my end users are not computer literate.

I have tried a few options like thickbox:

```
add_thickbox();
<a href="your url" class="thickbox">click here</a>
```

which works great on my edit.php page but my php knowledge is not good enough to get a proper grip on what to add to my functions.php or posts.php to get a pop up of some kind working on the edit posts page.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is you want when button is clicked you open the bootstrap modal

Comment: It can be I have no problem doing this but I need to know how to integrate this into the admin side of the site on the edit-post.php file which is entirely generated by php so adding this isn't as simple as adding a bootstrap modal as far as I am aware.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this, here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/g0pL3rkd/1/)

```
      <h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <span class="close">×</span>
              <h2>Modal Header</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes this would be what I want but I need to insert this into the admin edit page file on wordpress which is entirelly generated by php as far as I am aware.

Comment: its ok, this is only html & css code, you can use it in wordpress, it you want to use for edit purpose then add a form on modal and put the values using JQuery.

Comment: I understand this no problem, but how would I add this to the edit-post.php file on the admin side of wordpress as this page is entirely generated by php this is the issue that i have.